# Menu on android hardware option-button

Tags: android, codenameone

when pressing the hardware option-button on an android phone in my codenameone app, an empty menu is shown on the bottom of the app. Where can I set what should happen, when the android hardware option button is pressed?

Comment: Please provide what you have already done!

Comment: well - nothing because I have got no idea what to do...

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `Command` to the toolbar specifically to the side menu or overflow it should fill up this menu. However, it should do nothing if you didn't add a command so this might indicate a problem.

When you use standard API's like `addMaterialCommandToSideMenu` it will automatically create a menu see this screenshot from the kitchen sink when you press the menu button on an Android 6 device (OPO)

[image: Screenshot from Android device on menu button press]

Comment: Hmm - I populated the side menu with the call of addComponentToSideMenu() - but the overflow has some commands. Is it possible, that this combination (not commands directly in the side menu and some commands in the overflow) leads to an empty menu on the bottom when pressing the HW Options button? Is there any workaround to populate the bottom menu?

Comment: Are you using a special feature like the on-top side menu?

Comment: Not that I know - I don't use the on-top side menu.

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample, just tested this on the kitchen sink and it worked.